# How does one burn an iso image to a dvd using windows 8? Specifically Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: windows-8, dvd, startup-disk

I'm trying to create a bootable dvd for Ubuntu 12.04LTS using a Windows 8 machine.  The download of the .iso went well, but now I need to burn it to a dvd.  Instructions for Windows 7 say to right click on the .iso file and then select Windows Disc Image Burner.  No such option appears on Win 8.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't use Windows 8 but if this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjQqu_VQZD4) is correct its easy.

Comment: Sopunds as if you need DVD burning software.

Comment: This is falsely marked as duplicate. The user is aware of how to burn a disc image, but the instructions do not apply to his windows installation.

Answer (score 24):

When the *Burn Disk Option* isn't available in the menu when right clicking on an ISO image:

Right click on the ISO -> Choose Properties.

On the General tab
Change the "*Opens with*" option to "*Windows Explorer*".  Click Apply.

Go back. Right click on ISO -> Burn Disk Image. (Now the option is available)

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Image Burner. Right click on your ISO and select Windows Image Burner, pop in a blank DVD and select your DVD drive and click burn.